# How to fix (or avoid) backslash in filepath to vector layer (QGIS on windows)

Tags: qgis, r, layers, qgis-processing

Probably OS specific, I see this issue while using QGIS 2.14.11 and 2.18.3 versions on Windows64 platform.

When I import a vector to QGIS by `Layer | Add Layer | Add Vector Layer` the layer source writes backslash in its path. Can I fix this to forward slash?

**[EDIT]** This includes "Can I avoid backslash when I load vector files?"

[image]

These vector layers with backslash work fine usually, but it becomes troublesome if I try to read the layer from R script. For instance if I try to read a layer of .csv file (without geometry) from a Processing rsx script by `##Layer=table` it returns an error `Error 'u' used without hex digits in character string`.

Comment: I confirm the issue, but the same doesn't happen if you drag&drop the file in the canvas for importing it (in this case, I see the forward slashes). However, I don't understand how your second issue should be related to the first one if you are using a script.

Comment: @mgri thanks, it is interesting importing by drag&drop gives forward slashes. And sorry I was not clear about the issue. I have trouble reading the layer (after loading) from Processing Toolbox - R script. Edited my post to try to clarify the issue.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with r scripts, but can you give me an example of the filepath directly printed by the script? Is it something like `C:\GIS\temp\1.csv` or `C:\\GIS\\temp\\1.csv`? I think it should be sufficient using something like `print Layer`.

Comment: @mgri Unfortunately rsx scripts in processing does not have filepath in itself (you are correct about r scripts, that the filepath is set by user). Processing rsx scripts with `##Layer=` headerline reads layer as input and if it is set `##Layer=table` it try to read .csv table (in the Layers Panel) into the script by `read.csv()` function.

Comment: I'm confused: can't you run the line `print Layer` within your script for retrieving a filepath?

Comment: @mgri It is not possible retrieve layer path information from rsx script as far as I know.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I was thinking to a workaround when there was the backslash in the filepath, but if you can't get it from the code, I haven't any other idea by now. I'm sorry, but I never worked with R and I thinked there was the equivalent of `QgsVectorLayer()` inside it. After a simple search, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451783/get-file-path-of-r-script) thread could be useful for retrieving the filepath?

Comment: @mgri Many thanks! I will try to follow that lead. BTW, will you post your comments as answer? I confirm it works. I should have included "to avoid backslash" as solution to my issue, equal to "to fix".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm the issue, but the same doesn't happen if you drag&drop the file in the canvas for importing it (in this case, I see the forward slashes).

I'm unfamiliar with R scripts, but I think there would be a way to directly retrieve the filepath instead of loading the layer in the Layers Panel before running the script (I mean, something similar to `QgsVectorLayer()` for PyQGIS): after a simple search, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451783/get-file-path-of-r-script) thread could be useful for retrieving the filepath?

If you have success, or as an additional hint, you may also include a check on the filepath, for example:

```
filepath = 'C:\\GIS\\temp\\1.csv'
if '\\' in filepath:
    newpath = filepath.replace("\\", "/")
print newpath
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. I will try to follow the suggested lead, but the tip to avoid backslash is sufficient for me at the moment. If I can add, loading a vector file from `Browser Panel` is another way to avoid backslash. (I found it after your "drag&drop" suggestion.)

Comment: I'm glad this workaround worked! it's been so long time since I uploaded something from `Layer | Add Layer | Add Vector Layer` =)